# How to remap keys on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian-stretch, keyboard, input-device

I type using a Norman keyboard layout instead of the typical QWERTY one, so for example, where one would normally press the J key, I press the N key. How can I remap the keyboard in the Raspberry Pi software?

Comment: == "How do I remap keys in linux?" Which depends on whether you mean inside or outside of the GUI desktop.  The latter is in an "Xorg" context, X(org) being the name of the GUI userspace base layer.  See eg. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap

Comment: Thanks. That worked, although I still haven't figured out one thing with it. How can I remap a key so that it presses a combination of control and a key. For example, when I press backspace I want it to instead send control and backspace at the same time. For anyone else who might need help with keyboard remapping by the way, here's the video that I used to help me get started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5LJ9tO7G74.