# How to remap a keypress to one with a modifier?

Tags: raspbian, keyboard, archlinux

I am trying to remap my backspace key to control backspace. I remap the rest of my keyboard using xmodmap and I'm not sure how to remap one key to a key combination (ctrl + backspace). Please let me know if this is possible, or what the alternatives are if this is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: didn't you already ask? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/120787/how-to-remap-keys-on-raspberry-pi-4

Comment: think about it ... that is not remapping ... that is a hotkey ... keyboards do not know about multiple key combinations ... keyboards only know single key presses

Comment: Do you know how I could program that then?